# I can not run the task of rake refinery:testing:dummy

Tags: localization, refinerycms, refinery

guys! I am a newbie for Ruby on Rails and refinerycms. 
Currently, I am study the refinerycms. I want to find all the missing key so as to translate refinerycms. According to the tutorial, I should run the command

```
bundle exec rake refinery:testing:dummy_app
```

so as to  enable additional useful rake tasks. But when I run this command, it says

```
rake aborted! 
Don't know how to build task 'refinery_testing:dummy_app'
```

Does any one know the reason?

BTW, I have already added the gem "refinerycms-testing" to Gemfile and installed it already, and I also in the root directory of the project.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are not in the good directory.

```
cd vendor/extension/your_extension_name
bundle exec rake refinery:testing:dummy_app
```

Hope it helps,

-frbl